# How can I compute the reverse rank abundance of a species matrix?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R that contains species abundance data ordered by station and replicate sample. So, column one contains the station number, column two contains the replicate number, column three contains the species name, and column four contains the species abundance.

I want to add a new fifth column that contains the reverse rank abundance of a species per station/replicate combination (i.e., If there are four species in a station/replicate, I want the species with the lowest abundance to be given a value of 1, and the species with the highest abundance to be given a value of 4).

Here a sample code of the type of dataset I am working with:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,"A",2.34,
                            1,1,"B",4.32,
                            1,1,"C",2.46,
                            1,1,"D",6.32,
                            1,2,"A",3.54,
                            1,2,"B",7.67,
                            1,2,"D",3.45,
                            2,1,"D",4.67,
                            2,1,"E",6.54,
                            2,1,"G",5.67,
                            2,2,"B",2.31,
                            2,2,"G",1.12), ncol = 4, nrow = 12, byrow = TRUE
  
))

names(dat)[1] <- "station"
names(dat)[2] <- "replicate"
names(dat)[3] <- "taxa"
names(dat)[4] <- "abundance"

dat %>% 
  mutate(abundance = parse_number(abundance))
```

| station | replicate | taxa | abundance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 2.34 |
| 1 | 1 | B | 4.32 |
| 1 | 1 | C | 2.46 |
| 1 | 1 | D | 6.32 |
| 1 | 2 | A | 3.54 |
| 1 | 2 | B | 7.67 |
| 1 | 2 | D | 3.45 |
| 2 | 1 | D | 4.67 |
| 2 | 1 | E | 6.54 |
| 2 | 1 | G | 5.67 |
| 2 | 2 | B | 2.31 |
| 2 | 2 | G | 1.12 |

And here is some code to reorder the dataset so that it goes from the species with the lowest abundance to the species with the highest abundance per station/replicate:

```
dat %>% 
  arrange(abundance) %>% 
  arrange(replicate) %>% 
  arrange(station)
```

For some reason, I am unsure how to continue from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to rank by station/replicate, you first `group_by` this combination, and then create a new column with the `rank` value.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  group_by(station, replicate) %>%
  mutate(abundance = as.numeric(abundance),
         rank = rank(abundance))
```

**Output**

```
   station replicate taxa  abundance  rank
   <chr>   <chr>     <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1       1         A          2.34     1
 2 1       1         B          4.32     3
 3 1       1         C          2.46     2
 4 1       1         D          6.32     4
 5 1       2         A          3.54     2
 6 1       2         B          7.67     3
 7 1       2         D          3.45     1
 8 2       1         D          4.67     1
 9 2       1         E          6.54     3
10 2       1         G          5.67     2
11 2       2         B          2.31     2
12 2       2         G          1.12     1
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!